# What does the "of" do in this sentence?

Tags: american-english

I am reading some tech materials. Here is the sentence.

> So the security of the whole system depends on there being a Release.gpg file, which signs a Release file, and **of** apt checking that signature using gpg.

I am wondering what does the last **of** does here.

**Edit:** apt means advanced package tool, which is an interactive command-line tool for managing deb packages on different Linux distributions.

Comment: I think it is a mistake of some kind.

Comment: @Lambie do you think the **of** should be replaced with **on**? I mean **depends on**.

Comment: Yep, it's a tupo.

Comment: I don't think it's a typo — just a wee language usage hiccup what happens when engineers get a wiki.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Could you please provide more info in an answer? What does this have to do with wiki? Thank you.

Comment: The sentence is found on the [Debian SecureApt wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt). Wikis have a [variety of contributors](https://wiki.debian.org/RecentChanges), who may or may not be writers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely answer is that it's a typo for **"on,"** which would make perfect sense in context.

**Edit:** Some people in the comment section have gotten confused about the word "apt." This text comes from [a Debian Linux manual.](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/deb-pack-sign.en.html) "apt" is the name of the Debian package manager; since it's a shell command, its name is often written in lowercase. So in this instance, "apt" is not an adjective; it's a proper noun and the subject of "checking." Hence "apt checking" has the same structure as "there being."

Comment: But then how would "apt" function? That word is usually an adjective, but if it modifies the following gerund ("checking"), then that would violate the rule that a gerund is typically either noun-type (modified by the adjective "apt") or verb-type (taking the direct object "that signature").

Comment: Apt checking may stand in for appropriate authentication.

Comment: I agree with Yosef Baskin.  The process seems to be that 'Release.gpg creates a signature file.   But it is vital that either the signer or some third party checks that a valid signature has been created.  The sentence as it stands is not absolutely clear and could be clarified by writing down the steps as a list rather than as a single sentence.

Comment: @YosefBaskin This comes from the Debian Linux manual; "apt" is the name of the Debian package manager. (Despite being a proper noun, it's written in lowercase because it's a shell command.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan In short: "apt" is a proper noun, the name of a product, and it serves as the subject of "checking"; "apt checking" has the same structure as "there being."

Comment: @alphabet That makes sense, but it will be confusing for many people on ELU because it's not a commonly used proper noun (I suppose that it's jargon, according to your explanation) and lacks capitalization. If OP reads this, please edit your question to make clear what "apt" means in this context.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I've added a note about this to my answer. I myself hadn't noticed how this usage of "apt" would confuse the audience!

Comment: In the original manual, "apt" is emboldened and monospaced. But that's just a convention of that particular manual, and many/most people would just call it apt. (APT is also used, since it's an acronym, and some sources do use Apt...confusing!)

Comment: which signs a Release file, and **performs** apt checking that signature using gpg.

Comment: Hi @MarcInManhattan , I have edited my question. What do you mean by **on ELU**? What makes you think `apt` should be capitalized?

Comment: @krave Thank you, I think it's much clearer now. ELU is this site ("English Language & Usage"). "apt" is fine in lower case if that's how it's normally written, but most proper nouns are capitalized, so a reader could potentially confuse it with the adjective "apt" (as I did).

Comment: I suspect it's not so much a typo, as a sentence that got recast (originally it might have said _consists of_ or something like that) and the writer never noticed that the second half no longer matches. I think that's what Tinfoil Hat meant about a wiki: this easily happens when a second person can go in and edit what somebody else has written.

Comment: @ColinFine Ah, thank you! Didn't think about that. It does make sense.